# "Answer to the question" vs. "answer for the question" vs. "answer of the question"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions, to-for

> - The answer to the question.
> - The answer for the question.
> - The answer of the question.

Which is grammatical? What are the differences? And what is the preferred usage?

Comment: Maybe with a complete sentence you might see the differences. Being incomplete just distort the meaning. You might have asked:

Answer to - answer of - answer for and would have been the same effect.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

*The answer to the question* is the normal grammatical form.